# How to move subdirectories into another subdirectory within the same directory?

Tags: bash, mv

There is a directory `dir/`. It contains subdirectories `a`-`z`. I need to move subdirectories `a`-`y` into subdirectory `z`. 
If that's hard, then not `a`-`z`, but by providing a list of directories that need to be moved.

How can I do this in bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for me more secure way to use `find`

```
find dir/* -prune -type d -name "[a-y]" ! -name "z" -exec mv -t dir/z {} +
```

Comment: `name "[a-y]"` has no preceding dash - is that a typo or a syntax I don't know?

Answer (score 8):

Use brace expansion : http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html

For your case, do:

```
mv {a..y} z/
```

If you have list of directories, say `dir1`, `dir2`, and `dir3`, then do something like:

```
mv -t z/ dir1 dir2 dir3
```

Or maybe:

```
mv -t z/ dir{1..3}
```

### Brief Explanations:

- `-t` option means "target". It is usually used to avoid confusion in cases involving movement of multiple files/directories.
- Brace expansion work in the way that `{1..15}` will print all the numbers from 1 till 15, and `{a..f}` will print all alphabets from `a` till `f`.

Answer (score 1):

Note: this is not the cleanest way to do it (see shivams' answer for that), and just works if you *only* have the directories `a-z` inside `dir`.

---

I've always used the easier to remember

```
mv * z
```

which, of course, complains that

```
mv: cannot move ‘z’ to a subdirectory of itself, ‘z/z’
```

but otherwise does what you want.

This applies (at least) to `GNU coreutils`

Comment: To avoid complaints: `mv [!z] z`