# Move all but one sub-folder into that sub-folder

Tags: bash, directory

I have a directory named `temp`. Inside this folder, I have multiple sub-folders ( I don't know the exact number ). Now I create another sub-folder inside `temp` named `Untitled`. Now I want to move all the other sub-folders inside `Untitled`.

Let's say I have 3 folders inside temp named a,b,c. Now I create `Untitled`. So temp now contains 4 folders a,b,c and Untitled. After performing the operation temp will contain only the Untitled folder with Untitled containing a,b,c.

How can I achieve this using bash?

My Bash version ( on Ubuntu 16.04 )

```
GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: [How to move subdirectories into another subdirectory within the same directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/204072/22142)

Comment: @JeffSchaller I've edited the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have only the folders inside the main folder, the most simple way is this from `temp` (first `cd` to `temp`):

```
mv * Untitled
```

You'll get one error, saying:

```
mv: cannot move 'Untitled' to a subdirectory of itself, 'Untitled/Untitled'
```

If this is a problem for you, you can use a loop over `*` and moving each file one by one, skipping the target subfolder.

```
$ mkdir a b c
$ target_dir=Untitled
$ mkdir "$target_dir"
$ for f in *; do
if [ "$target_dir" == "$f" ]; then continue; fi; mv "$f" "$target_dir"; done
$ ls
Untitled
$ ls Untitled/
a  b  c
```

If there are files you want to skip, add the condition inside the loop before the `mv` command.

Comment: Use a pattern like `./*` to avoid issues with filenames that start with a dash and look like options.

Answer (score 3):

Briefly, and without errors, you could use bash's extended globbing to exclude the one directory that you want to omit:

```
shopt -s extglob
mv -- !(Untitled) Untitled
```

After ensuring that extended globbing is turned on, the `mv` command works by expanding the first parameter (`!(Untitled)`) into every file and directory in the current directory **except for** the one named "Untitled".  All of those files and directories are then moved into the `Untitled` directory.

If you only want to move *directories* from the current directory into Untitled, then add one character:

```
shopt -s extglob
mv -- !(Untitled)/ Untitled
```

... where the trailing `/` forces bash to match a directory instead of a file.

The above will omit dot-files by default (such as `.subdir`). If you want to pick those up as well, simply add:

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

For more on those shell options, see:

- [Bash filename expansion (globbing)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion)
- [Extended globbing for pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching)